# how can i change from python2 http request code to python3 Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I used python2.6 to write the following code, and I want change it to python3.2 and Requests:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import cookielib 
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))  
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

params = urllib.urlencode(dict(x = '0' , y = '0', url='login.php', password='1234',id='userid'))   
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://test.com/login_check.php', params)  
data = f.read()   
login_response = opener.open('http://aaa.com/bbs/confirm.php?')
htmlContent = login_response.read()   
print htmlContent   
response.close()
```

Comment: `.. I want change it to python3.2 and Requests` -- that's not a bad idea at all - go for it. Reading through http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html should enable you to write the function call you need. On a sidenote: the code you've posted will raise `NameError` for `response.close()` (perhaps this should be `login_response.close()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the docs, it's pretty simple: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

```
import requests

url = r'http://test.com/login_check.php'
parameters = {'x' : '0' ,
              'y' : '0', 
              'url':'login.php',
              'password':'1234',
              'id':'userid'}

login_response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
htmlContent = login_response.text
```

Comment: ok i see this document but same error
= is SyntaxError: invalid syntax in 'x'='0'
i don't understand
thank you

Comment: Try again, but make sure the `=` are `:` now. Make sure you try to understand what is going on though, rather than simply copy and pasting.

Comment: no i'm so tired. i'm many time to try. i choose python2.7! Thank you

Comment: @JefferyLim Yeah man, no problem. The code works in 2.7 too.

Comment: / Sorry, I mistake, plz give me a one tip! send requests x = 0 /thank you for your kindness/ if mechanize can support python 3. i can't try Request!